# plot with Matplotlib from tcp data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying trying to plot something with python. I have incoming data that update a float variable each iteration. I would like to plot it with matplotlib with respect to time. This is where I am stuck!

```
import socket
import sys

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(('', 5027))
socket.listen(5)
client, address = socket.accept()
print("{} connected".format( address ))
while True:
    response = client.recv(512)   
    print(response)
print ("close")
client.close()
stock.close()
```

response is the string variable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

body = '+1.33E+00@-6.54E+00@1.00E+00@-6.53E+00@'
one, two, three, four, five = body.split("@")
signal_1 = float(one)
signal_2 = float(two)
signal_3 = float(three)
signal_4 = float(four)
# Plot
t = 5
plt.plot(t, signal_1,t, signal_2,t, signal_3,t, signal_4,)
plt.show()
```

`body` is the simulated signal of the response variable in the first code. I want to plot the value of `signal_1` with respect to time.
Kindly assist me!

Answer (score 0):

Each series to plot has only one data point, e.g. the first one would be `(5,1.33)`.
The `plt.plot` command is a line plot. However, a line which connects a single point with itself remains invisible.

A possible solution is to set a marker (`marker="o"`) to show at the respective coordinates.

```
plt.plot(t, signal_1,t, signal_2,t, signal_3,t, signal_4, marker="o")
```

Of course you could also choose different markers for the respecive points,

```
plt.plot(t, signal_1, "ko", t, signal_2, "bs", t, signal_3, "rd", t, signal_4, "y^")
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I update the graph with respect to time like 10 points per second?

Comment: You can use interactive mode or `FuncAnimation`. There are a lot of examples around, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157538/python-matplotlib-loop-clear-and-show-different-plots-over-the-same-figure). I would suggest you try it out and if you're stuck, ask a new question with a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to draw a line and not a point. i.e. each time signal_1 is updated with a new value, it connects to the previous point.

Comment: This would require to store all previous values in a list, like `signal_1 = []` and then in each step `signal_1.append(float(one))`.

Comment: but then, it should have the same size as the time array .

Comment: Correct. You would need to create a list of times, `t = []; t.append(whatever)` and make sure it has the same size as the signal.